# Download Log Files from AWS S3 panic: runtime error:

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm to download all the log files in a particular bucket (eventually every bucket I have), here is the code I'm using

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

var (
    // variables empty for security
    Bucket         = ""                                               // Download from this bucket
    Prefix         = "" // Using this key prefix
    LocalDirectory = "s3logs"                                                    // Into this directory
)

func main() {

    client := s3.New(session.New(), &aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-west-1")})
    params := &s3.ListObjectsInput{Bucket: &Bucket, Prefix: &Prefix}

    manager := s3manager.NewDownloader(client)
    d := downloader{bucket: Bucket, dir: LocalDirectory, Downloader: manager}

    client.ListObjectsPages(params, d.eachPage)

}

type downloader struct {
    *s3manager.Downloader
    bucket, dir string
}

func (d *downloader) eachPage(page *s3.ListObjectsOutput, more bool) bool {
    for _, obj := range page.Contents {
        d.downloadToFile(*obj.Key)
    }

    return true
}

func (d *downloader) downloadToFile(key string) {
    // Create the directories in the path
    file := filepath.Join(d.dir, key)

    if err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(file), 0775); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("Downloading " + key)
    // Setup the local file
    fd, err := os.Create(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer fd.Close()

    // Download the file using the AWS SDK
    fmt.Printf("Downloading s3://%s/%s to %s...\n", d.bucket, key, file)
    params := &s3.GetObjectInput{Bucket: &d.bucket, Key: &key}
    d.Download(fd, params)
}
```

However when I run this code I receive a panic error

cannot use client (type *s3.S3) as type client.ConfigProvider in argument to s3manager.NewDownloader:
*s3.S3 does not implement client.ConfigProvider (missing ClientConfig method)

I have no idea what this code won't work, any thoughts and or fixes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing `nil` to `s3manager.NewDownloader` where it requires a `Session`

```
sess := session.New()
manager := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)
```

Comment: In my code, the client variable is an s3 session.  So I should be able to pass  client instead of nil into the NewDownloader.  However when I do I receive the error 

./test.go:25: cannot use client (type *s3.S3) as type client.ConfigProvider in argument to s3manager.NewDownloader:
 *s3.S3 does not implement client.ConfigProvider (missing ClientConfig method)


I've modified the error and source above. 

I also tried you're method above

session := session.New()
manager := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

but is throws the error session has no method New(), my code is based on aws example code.

Comment: @msanti: No, `client` isn't a `client.ConfigProvider`. Just create a session, and use it for both your client and manager.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the confusion